# http request and convert to json with comparision of json

Tags: javascript

- I want to make a http request  to a url lets say
         http://test1.com/info this will give me xml
- I want to convert
            this xml from 1 to json lets say json 1
- Now I make a  rest request to url lets
            say http://test2.com/myweb this returns a json lets say json 2

json 1

[

```
 {
        "id": "123",
        "testname": "test123",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test6"
    }

 {
        "id": "456",
        "testname": "test564",
        "name": "Ship Therasus",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test7"
    }

.... some 100 entries 
]
    and json 2 some like below

        [
            {
                "id": "123",
                "country": "USA",
                "state": "KA",
                "age": 24,
                "group": "g1"
            }

         {
                "id": "456",
                "country": "UK",
                "state": "MA",
                "age": 28,
                "group": "G2"
            }

        ...... 100 entries
        ]
```

Now Id is the constant thing between json1 and json2 I want to make a resultant json something like below lets call json3.I want to match the id and get country and state from json2 and append to json1

```
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "testname": "test123",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test6",
        "country":"USA",
         "state":"KA"
    }

 {
        "id": "456",
        "testname": "test564",
        "name": "Ship Therasus",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test7",
         "country":"UK",
         "state":"MA"
    }
]
```

Now wat i tried  for 1 and 3  but for 2 dont know wat to do and  to compare and combine I am not sure wat to do If  any help will be greatful

```
function fun() 
{
  var data="hello";
  $.post('http://localhost/ws/service.asmx/HelloWord',{},function(response) 
  {     data = response;
  }).error(function(){
  alert("Sorry could not proceed");
});

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var result=[];
    var x=[{"id": "123","testname": "test123", "name": "John Doe","active": true,"type": "test6"},{"id": "456", "testname": "test564", "name": "Ship Therasus", "active": true,"type": "test7" }];
var y = [{ "id": "123", "country": "USA", "state": "KA", "age": 24,"group": "g1"},{ "id": "456", "country": "UK", "state": "MA", "age": 28, "group": "G2"}];
for (i in x){
    for (j in y){
      if(x[i].id == y[j].id){

          result.push($.extend(x[i], y[j]));

          }
       }
   }  
console.log(result);

});
</script>
```